# TexStudio background in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am interested in building a beamer slide with a background similar to the one displayed when TexStudio is started, I don't know where to start. any ideas how to accomplish this?

Basically, I want to have a color gradient background with small sized equations distributed all over the slide

Here is the image I am talking about

[image: TexStudio Logo]

I am donde with the color background part but I am having difficulties to create random math equations, I've tried with the `\blindtext` package but I only want random math equations, not text. This is a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{arsenic}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}
\definecolor{darkspringgreen}{rgb}{0.09, 0.45, 0.27}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\shade[top color=arsenic,bottom color=darkspringgreen]
  ([shift={(0cm,-0cm)}]current page.north west)
     rectangle
  ([shift={(-0cm,0cm)}]current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%     
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\textcolor{white}{\blindmathpaper}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Licence permitting, `\includegraphics` seems the obvious way to go.

Comment: It is a nice idea but I dont wat to display the reflectors and te letters, I´ve edited the question to be more specific, I want to have a color gradient background with small sized equations distributed all over the slide

Comment: Then I suggest adding some code showing what you've tried. A gradient background should be pretty straightforward. Just look at Beamer's documentation.

Comment: Or make something suitable in Inkscape and include the image, if you don't want to expend effort on the documentation.

Comment: I have edited my question once again with a MWE, now my question is just about the random math expressions.

Comment: @PaulLara Off topic: while this design might (or might not) look good, please make sure that it does not reduce the readability of your slides -- especially don't just look on your screen but have a test run with projected slides.

Answer (score 8):

This is the best I can do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\moremathintolatex}{
    \blindtext@formula
    \blindtext@formula
    \blindtext@formula
    \blindtext@formula
    \blindtext@formula
    \blindtext@formula
    \relax%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{arsenic}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}
\definecolor{darkspringgreen}{rgb}{0.09, 0.45, 0.27}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \shade[top color=arsenic,bottom color=darkspringgreen]
    ([shift={(0cm,-0cm)}]current page.north west)
    rectangle
    ([shift={(-0cm,0cm)}]current page.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%     
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \textcolor{white}{\moremathintolatex}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As the final result is not too nice, consider this just a possible starting point. I've tried to introduce some randomness in CarLaTeX's solution.

First I've stolen `blintext` formula and converted it to a command. Second this command is used as `text` into a `node` which is randomly placed on background.

You can decide how many formulas to use, which formulas to use, and how to define their placement.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\moremathintolatex}{
    \blindtext@formula
    \relax%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\myformula}[1][0]{%
\ifcase#1%
$\displaystyle\bar x = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} x_i = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \dots{} + x_n}{n}$
\or 
$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2} \mathrm{d}x =
\frac12\sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2}}
\mathrm{d}x\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha y^2}\mathrm{d}y =
\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}$
\or 
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_0q^k = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n a_0q^k =
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_0\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q} = \frac{a_0}{1-q}$
\or 
$\displaystyle x_{1,2}=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} = \frac{-p \pm \sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2}$
\or 
$\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial y^2} +
\frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial z^2} =
\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\Phi}{\partial t^2}$
\or 
$\displaystyle\sqrt[n]{a} \cdot \sqrt[n]{b} = \sqrt[n]{ab}$
\or 
$\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}}{\sqrt[n]{b}} = \sqrt[n]{\frac{a}{b}}$
\or 
$\displaystyle a\sqrt[n]{b} = \sqrt[n]{a^n b}$
\fi%
}

\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{arsenic}{rgb}{0.23, 0.27, 0.29}
\definecolor{darkspringgreen}{rgb}{0.09, 0.45, 0.27}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \shade[top color=arsenic,bottom color=darkspringgreen]
    ([shift={(0cm,-0cm)}]current page.north west)
    rectangle
    ([shift={(-0cm,0cm)}]current page.south east);
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,8}
        \node[white] at ([shift={(3*rand,3*rand)}]current page.center){\myformula[\i]};
    \end{tikzpicture}%     
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]